# What does WPF call the "Menu" key?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, keyboard

I'm looking at the keys defined here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key.aspx

and I don't see one which obviously corresponds to the menu key:
[image: menu key image]

Which key am I looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key you are looking for is `Key.Apps`.

Here is a working example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this currently, but I believe it is `Key.Apps`